# I get an error while using \cormark[1] in my latex document

Tags: templates

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Tackling the bottlenecks of ...}    
\shortauthors{Reza et~al.}  
\title [mode = title]{Tackling the bottlenecks of videos}  
\author[1]{Morteza}[role=senior advisor,
            orcid=0000-0000-0000-0000]
\cormark[1]
\fnmark[1]
\ead{reza@example.com}
\ead[url]{www.example.com}
\credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology, Softwar}
\affiliation[1]{organization={University of example},
            addressline={V94 T9PX}, 
            city={example},
%       citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
%         postcode={}, 
            state={},
            country={Ireland}}
```

and the rest of the document. Whenever I run this code, I receive the following error:

...to_str:N \csgdef {mark@corau\theau@
}{1}}
l.86 \cormark[1]

?

I don't understand why I should receive it at this coding stage. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: don't authblk with this class.